# How can I make eclipse recognize projects from another computer?

Tags: java, eclipse

I just copied workspace folder from another computer and pasted

but eclipse do not recognize projects. I want eclipse to recognize

projects and subsources. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start Eclipse and do

File -> Import... -> General -> Existing projects into workspace

Select the directory you copied the workspace to as a root directory. You will be prompted for the projects to import.

Answer (score 1):

I have used import, from there I select project and browse till I find the project, then I select and click import. This has always worked for me, are you trying to import a non-eclipse project?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make manual project by making a folder and make it recognized as Eclipse project, just add two files `.project` and `.classpath`, you can see their content from any Eclipse project you already have.